# jQuery & Isotope sort by numbers within an element

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do specific type of sorting, usually I would sort by a class id but this time I'm trying to achieve something different.

OK here's the example code:

```
<div class="points-wrapper">

<span class="rewards-points">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.Points">1000</span> Points
</span>

<span class="rewards-points">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.Points">5000</span> Points
</span>

<span class="rewards-points">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.Points">5000</span> Points
</span>

</div>
```

Sorting Buttons below.

```
<div id="sorts" class="button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-value="original-order">original order</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="points">500</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="points">1000</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="points">2000</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="points">3000</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="points">5000</button>
</div>
```

This is a smaller example of what I'm actually working on, the real one has about 30 different items all with various points count.

I'm trying to figure out how to sort according to the points count within the span. Options would be something along the lines of "0 - 1000", "1000 - 5000", "5000 - "10000" etc.

How can sort that using jQuery and Isotope.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** SORTING ***

So I assume the `rewards-points` class is your isotope item, hence:

```
var container = $('#container').isotope({
itemSelector: '.rewards-points',  
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
    getSortData: {
        points: function(item){
            return parseFloat($(item).find(".number").text());
        }
    }
});

container.isotope({ sortBy: 'points' });
```

The `getSortData` function returns a value for Isotope to sort by, then the `sortBy` is set to the name we set in the `getSortData` function.

Details here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html

*** SORTING WITH FILTERING ***

You'll need to use the filter function, like so:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).text() == "All"){
        container.isotope({ filter: function() { return true; } });
    }
    else
    {
        var btnVal = parseFloat($(this).text());
        container.isotope({ filter: function() {
            var itemVal = parseFloat($(this).find(".number").text());
            return btnVal == itemVal;
        }});
    }

});
```

See: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

I think that should sort it... but I would say if you can change your markup, use the `data` attributes to hold values, and classes to hold the selectors and it'll make working with isotope much easier!

Update fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y59S2/3/

Again, tiding up your HTML would make it significantly easier, so something to consider.

Comment: So I've implemented your code, but I'm having trouble with the set up for the sorting buttons. I've added the code above.

Comment: Sorry I asked this question the wrong way, what I was supposed to ask for is how to filter items by the number in the span. I'll have to post this question again.

Comment: Gave it a shot on fiddle, doesn't work not sure if I set it up right. http://jsfiddle.net/Covanant/Y59S2/

Comment: OK, updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y59S2/2/ generally had a tidy up etc... I've set the filter to equals, but you can change to greater than, less then if you wish. If you can change the HTML markup it would make your life massively easier! Your spans need to be Block level to work for example.

Comment: It works except for the "All" button, it doesn't seem to remove the isotope-hidden class when clicked.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read any of the documentation? Well, as you seem to wish for the answer without having to do any research: http://jsfiddle.net/Y59S2/3/

Comment: '// change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });'

I tried the filtering page example, what document could I have read in that space of time that would've helped me figure out that one line of code was the issue. I'm a beginner in JS, can't figure it out ask a question, thought that's how it worked. Either way I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: No problem - I had screaming children at the time so a little frazzled! Stack Overflow is about http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ rather than "Give me the answer" - Ideally with the right questions, and the right answers you get to learn - if you don't understand why something works, feel free to ask why a piece of code is doing that, that way we all improve from it! So in this instance, to show all we need to `return true` from the filter function for all elements!

Comment: Hello, I know its an old thread, can you please guide me, if I can add *multiple* `sortBy` in the `container.isotope({ sortBy: 'points' });` ??, i.e can I do `container.isotope({ sortBy: 'points' }, { sortBy: 'hotels' }, { sortBy: 'cruises' });` since I have several sort href functions, functions, but the anchor never wires up ocrrectly and I saw your  , I was wondering what I was missing? [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73928055/unable-to-prevent-client-side-js-href-function-click-link-from-submit-to-server)